# Loading Java Applet ... network: Cache entry not found

Tags: java, applet

I have done with All stuff with Applet. I published the applet on the server. It is running fine from IE on all machines. But it is not running on firefox. Below is the stack trace for the same. Please advise for the same.

Code of Applet:

```
 public void init()
    {
showInst();
}
public void showInst()
    {

        Inst inst = new ANTInst();
     JFrame app = new JFrame("Test App");
        app.getContentPane().add(instruction, "Center");
        app.setResizable(false);
        instruction.setFrameHandler(app);
        app.show();

   }
basic: Loading Java Applet ...
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.attentiontranslator.com/ant_test/, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.attentiontranslator.com/ant_test/ANT.class, version: null]


<applet  code=ANT.class width=300 height=300>
</applet>
```

I have check that java is installed with updated version
Please find more logs below

```
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value null
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter$GrayBoxProgressListener@13d93f4
basic: Loading Java Applet ...
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.attentiontranslator.com/ant_test/, version: null]
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://www.attentiontranslator.com/ant_test/ANT.class, version: null]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)`  Why is the applet ever calling `System.exit(n)`.  (And did I not ask you that the other day?)

Comment: What is the code of the `init()` & `start()` methods?

Comment: code for Init() function has been in Original question

Comment: Please help since  same applet is running on firefox and IE in my machine and it is not running from my coleagues machines. we are on the same network and having same Java and JRE installed. I want to run the applet on multiple browser on all the machines

Comment: Answer to first comment: AccesscontrolException can be a issue with permission which should be given in java.policy file . And System.exit(0) is for closing the applet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6722/discussion-between-andrew-thompson-and-maneesh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you [checked](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) that the [Java plugin](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Using%20the%20Java%20plugin%20with%20Firefox) is working in Firefox?

Edit:
Apparently, FF [requires](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/firefox_newplugin.xml) Java 6 Update 10 (or above) to work.

Comment: Applet running on firefox on my machine but on other machine having java upadate and plugin both are updated and still having problem. I am adding screen shot java installed and plugin in my original question

Comment: problem is solved. But I still searching why some times firefox stops responding( I mean crashed after some times) on applet remote loading, is it applet issue or JVM fault?

Answer (score 0):

I had made these changes and after that it was working fine for me after searching a lot.

Go to

- Control panel
- Java Control Panel
- Java Tab View
- IN run time parameters add this line

  ```
  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
  ```